# why does the font of my item navigation drawer change after set text on an item?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

these are my functions:

in this function I defined drawer layout after clicking on some button and called set navigation items.

```
private void setNavigationView() {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawable_main);
    ImageView menuBtn = findViewById(R.id.drawer_btn);
    menuBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT));

    setNavigationItems();

}
```

at this function I set the name of city that was saved in shared preference and called some items:

```
private void setNavigationItems() {

    sharedPrfManager = new SharedPrfManager(MainActivity.this);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView_id);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    setItemNavigation();
    btn_join = header.findViewById(R.id.button_joinOrEnter);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.drawer_userpannel:

                break;
            case R.id.drawer_chooseCity:
                Intent intentGetCity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CityActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intentGetCity , 2);

                break;
            case R.id.drawer_favorites:

                break;
            case R.id.drawer_connect_us:

                break;
            case R.id.drawer_rate_app:

                break;
            case R.id.drawer_shares:

                break;


        }

        return true;
    });

}
```

at this function I have got city selected from city activity then I called setItemNavigation() for setting city name from shared preferance:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (data != null){
            sharedPrfManager.saveCity(data.getStringExtra("nameCity"),data.getIntExtra("idCity",0));
            setItemNavigation();
        }
    }
}

private void setItemNavigation() {

    Menu menuitemView = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menucity = menuitemView.findItem(R.id.drawer_chooseCity);
    if (sharedPrfManager.getCityId() != 0)
    {
        menucity.setTitle( "انتخاب شهر(" + sharedPrfManager.getCityName() + ")");
    }
}
```

my menu items is there:

```
            <item
                android:id="@+id/drawer_userpannel"
                android:title="@string/str_user_pannel"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_user_pannel"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/drawer_chooseCity"
                android:title="@string/str_choose_city"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/drawer_favorites"
                android:title="@string/str_favorites"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_heart"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/drawer_connect_us"
                android:title="@string/str_connect_us"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_us"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/drawer_rate_app"
                android:title="@string/str_rate_app"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/drawer_shares"
                android:title="@string/str_shares"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"/>
```

[When I select city before starting main activity, my navigation drawer items' font work properly:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N04od.png)

[work properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycSgI.png)

[But when I choose city after starting activity on select choose city item, the font of some items change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsvEQ.png)

you can see that I called the same function for select city before using program and after starting program then choose city from navigation items but I don't know why some of my item's font change after setting the text of one item!
thanks for your replys.

Answer (score 0):

my first suggestion is use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
but you can also use this function to set the font to your navigation manually:

write this onResume:

```
        Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();

        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem mi = m.getItem(i);

            //for aapplying a font to subMenu ...
            SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
            if (subMenu != null && subMenu.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < subMenu.size(); j++) {
                    MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                    applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
                }
            }

            //the method we have create in activity
            applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
        }
```

and use this function to set font:

```
private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Vazir-Bold-FD.ttf");
            SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
            mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
        }
```